# Number-system conversion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, system

I wrote the following program for MatLab that converts numbers from decimal-system to other systems with base from 2 (binary) through 16 (hexademical). I faced with problems when the program translates to systems, starting from base 10. In that case remainder must be written in a way, like `10=A`, `11=B` and so on. How is it possible to make it? Should I use switch-case for this purpose? Thank you!

```
clc
clear all
dec = input('dec=');
n = input('select number system n=');
if n>=2 && n<=16
    i = 0;
    p=dec;
    while p>0
        dec=p;
        i = i + 1;
        p = fix(dec/n);
        r = mod(dec, n);
        base(i) = num2str(r);
    end
    base = fliplr(base);
    disp(['base=' num2str(base)]);
else
    disp('error');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function exists as the builtin [`dec2base`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2base.html). If you have a look at its source code via

```
edit dec2base
```

you will see that this function builds a vector of numbers first and then uses it to index into the character array `symbols = '0123456789ABCDEFG...'`. You could use the same approach instead of `num2str`. `base(i) = symbols(r+1)` should do it.

BTW:

- In the `disp` line you are using `num2str` on something that is already a string.
- Instead of using `disp('error')`, you could actually produce an error message via `error('Choose base b as 2<=b<=16')`.
- Instead of `base(i)` you could use `base(end+1) = ...` to get rid of the variable `i`.

Comment: Congrats on the golden badge!

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thanks! Although the Fanatic-badge is really only for sticking around here every day. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp.could you please help me with another problem, which is program that does the inverse calculations?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326142/number-system-conversion-in-matlab-from-different-system-to-decimal)